# /authorize.php redirects to ssl and is not found after trying to update a module in Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal-7

I am trying to update a module in Drupal 7.43 (notice: this installation has been patched for SA-CORE-2018-004). When setting up the FTP connection settings and clicking continue the /authorize.php is being redirected to https, and giving me a message "The requested URL /authorize.php was not found on this server". I am not able to get around this issue.

I've searched for "authorize.php not found drupal 7" and found a lot of issues, but they're all are slightly different then this one.

This issue is occuring on a development environment (a fresh copy from the live website) for testing updates (module and drupal core).
The live website is running via SSL, so I've changed the .htaccess on the development environment to run via http. Everything is working fine until I am trying to install the module updates.

Further information:

- This is a multi-domain setup
- .htaccess is changed to run the development environment via http instead of https
- In settings.php there is no $baseUrl defined
- Webserver: Apache/2.2.23 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.23 OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips DAV/2 PHP/5.3.28
- No related status logs
- Cleared caches

Has somebody experienced this issue before, or can somebody point me to the right direction?

Comment: i hope you fean SFTP

Comment: you should set up ssl on your dev machine, which should mirror production as closely as possible, rather than trying to hack a fix in

Comment: @delboy1978uk I totally agree that the dev machine should mirror production closely and should run via ssl. But in this case, we don't have the option to run ssl on this temporary machine. We just want to see if the update will break other things or can be run safely. 

We never had this issue before and cannot find any problems with the configuration of the installation.

Comment: what lamp stack are you using? would it be too much trouble to try it in a docker box? i can give you a config, two commands and you have a full stack with SSL at your disposal

Comment: @delboy1978uk the stack is exactly the same as the production server. The drupal installation is an exact clone. The only difference is that the development installation is not redirecting to HTTPS (which would be better if it was).

Anyway, this setup of the development environment has worked before (also HTTP) so I am not sure why this problem occurs now. It seems to be Drupal related issue, there are multiple issues with the authorize.php on the web, but all slightly different.

Thanks for pointing out Docker, but then it would no longer be an exact mirror of the production setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a workaround for my issue. Since I am able to run update.php, I've manually replaced the old module files with the new ones (should have thought about this earlier).